# Get the domain name in a Drupal/Symfony controller

Tags: php, symfony, url, drupal

I have a website built in drupal 9. There are several domains pointing to the web site. In my controller I need to know which one was used in the user's browser. I pass the `RequestStack` into my controller, but I can only get to the primary domain. I need to know Which domain the user entered in their browser.

Comment: You can get the host from the request stack like this `$requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getHost();`.

Comment: Super global variable $_SERVER could be useful.

Comment: $requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->getHost(); returns the primary domain, not the doamin that the user typed in in the browser.

Comment: @user3519410, it must be redirecting beforehand then (via vhost or dns). When you type the domain into your browser, does it redirect to your primary domain?

Comment: When i type the domain in my browser the browser still displays the address/URL I typed.It does not replace it with the primary domain.